# How to pick up the smallest distance for car?

Tags: gps, 8.1-oreo, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-3

I’m in a situation where even with forbidding motorway I’m ending up with a 110 Km deviation to the north or the south for driving straight to the east.
I want the shortest path in Km even if takes way longer and burn more fuel (fuel economic routes also have such high deviation).

The best way to achieve this is to configure for pedestrian mode *(I checked in that case the route is almost a straight line instead of a curve with car mode whatever the guiding software)*. The problem is I’m not find taking stairs with the car.

So how to get the shortest path which excludes roads where cars can’t go through ?

Comment: Dirt roads need to be in the map provider's database as a routable path else you are stuck to workarounds as you've described. Have you checked if the map provider can provide bicycle directions?

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes it can. The system can also use uses dirt roads in car mode provided it’s allowed to drive on them. The problem is it simply compute a route with a huge deviation even in fuel econmic mode instead.

Comment: @MorrisonChang because car mode always uses roads with regular speed in fuel economic mode or the highest speed if configured for the fastest route. Dirt roads, as well as roads with a lot of curve and paths through cities are used only as fallback.

Comment: Not sure how you are expecting an answer when you don't specify what map providers (Google, Here, OpenStreetMaps, TomTom, etc) you are using/tried or the area/region/country you are trying to navigate through in case a different map provider can give what you are looking for.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I don’t care about the map provider. If something works on Openstreetmap then I’ll switch to Openstreetmap.

Comment: Then at least list the country you are trying to navigate through, preferably with an example (image or drawing) of what you are seeing with xyz map provider and what you want to see.

Comment: @MorrisonChang France. But I don t see how this is related since all services I found only propose the fastest route. The description of the exact case can t be translated in English.